# How to join two dtypes and two arrays (numpy)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-dtype

I'm trying to join two arrays into one:
The first one is the easiest being just:

```
["str".....]
```

with the dtype:

```
dtype('S22')
```

The second one being a bit more complicated:

```
[([(int, "str"),(int, "str")],)...]
```

with the dtype:

```
dtype([('table_pointer', [('table', '<i2'), ('pointer', 'S22')], (2,))])
```

And when i try to join them with np.array:

```
pTable = np.array([table1, table2], dtype = [('keys', table1), ('vals', table2)])
```

I get the following error:

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'str'
```

I've tried using np.stack, np.vstack and np.concatenate, but they all refused to accept dtypes with subarrays

Here is the full code:

```
    dtTable1 = np.dtype("<S22")
    table1 = np.fromiter(pointerTable.keys(), dtTable1)
    dt = np.dtype([('pointer', np.int16),('table',"<S22")])
    dtTable2 = np.dtype([('table_pointer', dt, (2))])
    table2 = np.fromiter(pointerTable.values(), dtype = dtTable2)
    pTable = np.array([table1, table2 ], dtype = [('keys', dtTable1 ), ('vals', dtTable2)])
```

It's supposed to create a array containing the two like:

```
array(array(Table1),array(Table2)
```

The arrays are both the same length

Comment: Do you want to create a rec-array containing a rec-array and a str array? Something with a dtype of (roughly) `[S22, [S22, i2]]`?

Comment: did you look at the errors? All the stacks use concatenate.

Comment: What's supposed to be the result dtype?

Comment: @hpaulj They don't share dtype which leads to this error:
`The DType <class 'numpy.dtypes.BytesDType'> could not be promoted by <class 'numpy.dtypes.VoidDType'>. This means that no common DType exists for the given inputs. For example they cannot be stored in a single array unless the dtype is `object`. The full list of DTypes is: (<class 'numpy.dtypes.BytesDType'>, <class 'numpy.dtypes.VoidDType'>)`

Comment: @hpaulj something in the lines of:
[S22[(i2, S22), (i22,S22)]]
Would it be imposible to insert a value into the left most S22?
I'm thinking about using rec_array()?

Comment: I Asked what `dtype`?  You have no business joining these arrays if you can be clear about that.

Comment: @hpaulj I just took the easy way out and returned to separate arrays which worked

Comment: yes, often a list is easier to create and use than a complex array (whether object dtype or compound dtype)